# Linq query to implement where clause on child entities - EF Core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

What I'm trying to do should be really easy, but I just can't work it out!

I have a parent entity called **Players** and a child entity called **PlayerTrainingEvents**. *(PlayerTrainingEvents is actually a join table, but I'm not involving more than these two tables in this example).*

I want to bring back ***all*** the Players (not just the ones with related PlayerTrainingEvents) ***AND*** their related PlayerTrainingEvents for a given TrainingEventID.

These are the (simplified) entities and their relationship:

[image]

Here is some example data:

[image]

Using the above example data, if I want to show all the Players with their PlayerTrainingEvents for TrainingEventID 3, I should get the following results:

[image]

In SQL, it's really easy:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Players p
  left join PlayerTrainingEvents pte on p.ID = pte.PlayerID and pte.TrainingEventID = 3
```

In Linq, the nearest I can get is:

```
var results = await _context.Players
            .Include(p => p.PlayerTrainingEvents.Where(pte => pte.TrainingEventID == id)).ToListAsync();
```

...but the above code results in an error: "InvalidOperationException: Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid".

As you can probably tell, I'm still quite new to EF. Having been able to anything I want easily in SQL, I'm struggling with how EF is supposed to make things easier!

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos and @DivZero I will remove my asnwer as it did not seem to help. But if you look at what `Include` does perform a `join` on the entities when it is fetched from sql. It is possible that on this question I did not know that `PlayerTrainingEvents` was not a navigation property so that is likely the reason for the error when attempting my answer.

Comment: I appreciate your help - thanks

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the answers/comments I received. I have managed to get the below query to work. This queries the Players first and then performs an outer join with the PlayerTrainingEvents.

```
from p in Players
join pte in PlayerTrainingEvents on new { PlayerId = p.ID, TrainingEventID = 3 } 
                                 equals new { PlayerId = pte.PlayerID, TrainingEventID = pte.TrainingEventID } into ptes
from pte in ptes.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new  { p.ID, pte.TrainingEventID, pte.AttendanceCode }
```

That just seems a lot of code for what is a *very* simple SQL query however. I still think SQL is easier but perhaps I just need to do some studying! If anyone has a better solution, I'd be really interested to see it.